# Sync/convert PostgreSQL tables from Foxpro (.dbf) databases

Tags: postgresql, foxpro, foreign-data-wrapper

We are using a business management system that is using Foxpro databases and we want to be able to sync some information from those tables to PostgreSQL for some other things that we are doing apart from the management system.

I am wondering what the best way is to sync data from Foxpro (.dbf) databases to PostgreSQL-9.4.

I tried to use the Foreign Data Wrapper inside of PostgreSQL to connect with an ODBC connection but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You need to know what version of FoxPro they were created with. The Microsoft ODBC driver for Visual FoxPro only works with tables that use VFP 6 and earlier functionality. If your tables use anything added after that (such as autoincrementing integer fields), you need to use the OLE DB driver, or the Sybase Advantage Database Server ODBC driver.

Comment: We decided to reach out to [Omega Sync](https://www.spectralcore.com/omegasync) and they will write a script so that we can sync from Foxpro (.dbf) to Postgres!